# Geojson to Topojson in node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql-9.1, postgis, topojson

I have a shape file in my postGIS database.I have retrieved that into geojson in node.js by using the following code.

```
var moisql = 'SELECT *, (ST_AsGeoJSON(geom))  from xxx;'
```

Works fine..But my requirement is i have to convert this geojson file into "`TOPOJSON`".

SO i have this code:

```
topojsonOutput = topojson.topology({'collection': geojsonString});
```

But still i am retrieving geojson file as output..SO please guide me to achieve this..Thanks in advance.

Also when i googled i got this code:

```
var collection = {type: "FeatureCollection", features: […]}; // GeoJSON
var topology = topojson.topology({collection: collection}); // convert to TopoJSON
console.log(topology.objects.collection); // inspect TopoJSON
```

But totally i can't understand this..What i have to give in place of features[..] and collections..

Answer (score 2):

There's a PostGIS [AsTopoJSON](http://postgis.net/docs/AsTopoJSON.html) function available for PostGIS 2.1.0 and greater.  Alternatively, there's the [postgis2geojson](https://github.com/jczaplew/postgis2geojson) conversion tool; you might want to look at how it wraps the snippets that `ST_AsGeoJSON` returns.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from example [here](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/blob/master/test/topology-test.js).

```
var topology = topojson.topology({
        collection: {
          type: "FeatureCollection",
          features: [
            {type: "Feature", geometry: {type: "LineString", coordinates: [[.1, .2], [.3, .4]]}},
            {type: "Feature", geometry: {type: "Polygon", coordinates: [[[.5, .6], [.7, .8]]]}}
          ]
        }
      });
```